# Create a unique float id?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I don't know how to phrase this question, but I'm trying to do this:

```
alter table [TEMP]
add SEQID int identity(1,1)
```

This works; however, what I really need is a float column instead of an int:

```
alter table [TEMP]
add SEQID **FLOAT** identity(1,1)
```

I think this is illegal. Please let me know if it is not.
Is there a work around to getting a float ID column?

Edit: Is there a way to create the identity column as int, then remove the identity attribute, and then convert the column to a float?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want a float identity column? You get an identity column when you do not care for its value as long as it is unique per table; why then would you care about its *type*?

Comment: Do you really need a big int instead of an integer?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it has to do with what type of data the legacy system is expecting; of which I have no control

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know the difference b/t the two so I assume no.

Comment: You would use a big int if you needed more values than are available with an integer.  But that is not why you need this.

Comment: You say in your comments  "...it has to do with what type of data the legacy system is expecting; of which I have no control" at this time, my question is: why a view is not enough? create view ... convert( float, id) as id, ...

Comment: @danihp I'm not sure what you are saying. I'm sorry.

Comment: @ericf - You need to realize that for you to actually get a fixed number (1, 2, 3), even if it has a decimal, you need an exact datatype to get this. `FLOAT` doesn't give you that, if you try to insert a `1` it can insert a `0.99999999` and then you wouldn't have an identity. That's why it throws an error with that datatype, use an exact datatype for this

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want as:

```
create table temp (
    id int identity(1,1),
    fid as cast(id as float)
)
```

This adds the id as an integer but then has another column that is computed by converting it to float.

Why are you creating new ids for a legacy system?

Or, you can add the computed column to an existing table:

```
alter table temp add fid as cast(id as float)
```

Comment: This works when you want to create the table, not when you want to alter an existing table

Comment: It's not a real id per se. The data can only be uploaded in chunks, so it is more like a place holder.

Comment: @Lamak can I use Alter Table, new column?

Comment: I modified the answer with the alter table statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm getting: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'column'

Comment: Sorry about that. I actually tested the code and it worked; I just didn't type it in correctly. In my mind, the alter table statement should be "alter table <t> add column <c>" -- after all, I might want to add a constraint, or an index, or a partition. But, SQL doesn't use that keyword.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand why you want a floating point ID. That column is usually just stored as an int (bigint, smallint, depends on the table...) but an int will uniquely identify each row of the table sufficiently to allow you to query each of them without data contamination. You just have to make sure to Join the tables correctly.

If you're really sure about using float, then I think this would suffice, unless I'm missing something:

```
alter table [TEMP]
add SEQID float identity(1,1)
```

Comment: I get this error: Identity column 'SEQID' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, and constrained to be nonnullable.

Comment: Any column marked as "identity" is reserved as being an int-type. All databases are designed around this concept, so the ID column has to be an int. Actually, I think [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) requires it. If you really truely want an ID column stored as a float, you're going to have to forgo the identity marker and make it a normal column. All incrementation on its part will have to be handled programmatically, either in code or a stored procedure.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is kind of a downside of relational databases. Fortunately, they're a lot nicer to use then non-relational ones! I work on a few Legacy databases as well; I understand the frustration.

Comment: RoboGen, is there a way to create the identity column, then remove the identity attribute, and then convert to a float?

Comment: @RoboGen Apologies if I misunderstood your reply and comments, but `float` is not allowed as an IDENTITY column in SQL Server (although `decimal` is) and "all databases" are not designed around either integers or identity columns. You probably didn't mean that, but your wording implies it.

Comment: @Pondlife Is there a way to create the identity column as int, then remove the identity attribute, and then convert the column to a float?

Comment: @ericf No, so far I don't think you've actually explained why you want to do this, although several people have asked you. You mentioned a legacy system, but you haven't told us what the real problem is. Instead of asking us how to implement a solution that isn't possible anyway, I suggest you explain your real problem (data mapping or replication, perhaps?) and ask for suggestions. I'm sorry if this sounds harsh or unhelpful.

Comment: @Pondlife not a worry. I guess I am not sure myself.